# Excel VBA: Disabling code after expiration period

Tags: excel, vba

Have a client that wants to "sunset" their Excel app so that VBA code will not work in 120d. They understand that any solution will not work 100% but any ideas besides checking today's date vs. a stored first used date?

Comment: The approach you describe seems like the obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to compare the differences between two dates, with one of the dates being the arbitrary "Launch" date and the second date being today.

Easiest way is to use the function DateDiff (https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php):

```
DateDiff("d","5/1/2018",Date())
```

This will return a number representing number of days ("d"...if you wanted to have the answer be in months you could use "m", etc.) between the two dates. Since I did this on 5/17/18, my Date() function returns 5/17/18, and this takes the difference between the two, putting out 16.

So the code should be:

```
Dim dif As Single
Dim launch As String

launch = "1/1/2018" 'arbitrary start date

dif = DateDiff("d", launch, Date())

If dif > 120 Then 'on May 17th, this number is 136
    MsgBox "Your VBA is out of date"
    Exit Sub
Else
    'Do the rest of your code
End If
```